# Create section in the admin panel CMS comfy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system, comfortable-mexican-sofa

I inherited a project that uses COMFY CMS. I have no experience with this CMS so far. I have to create a page in the admin area - right below Sites, Layouts, Pages, Snippets, Files etc.

I read the https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa/wiki/HowTo:-Reusing-Admin-Area , but it didn't help.

I created controller **( app/controllers/admin/server_management_controller.rb)** and view **(/app/views/comfy/admin/emails/index.html.haml)**.

Controller:

```
class Admin::ServerManagementController < Comfy::Admin::Cms::BaseController

    def index 

    end
end
```

The view:

```
.page-header
  %h2= 'Index'
```

And the corresponding route:

```
namespace :admin do
      get ' ' => 'server_management#index', as: :server_management
```

When I navigate to that page I get error:

> Admin::ServerManagementController#index is missing a template for this request format and variant.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

As per that error message, your template is in the wrong spot. Rails will load templates derived from the controller class. So `Admin::ServerManagementController#index` needs a view in `app/views/admin/server_management/index.html.haml`